# C Algorithm to find base system with the highest number of nulls in the end

Tags: c, numbers, system

As title says, I have to find the base system of given number which has the highest number of nulls in the end. For example if I have number 100 000, the answer is 10, because in 10 system there is the highest amount of nulls. Answer for number 54 would be 3, because in 3 numeral system it looks like 2000 (the highest amount of nulls in the end). I've written a program which works fine, but the problem comes if the number exceeds maximum of integer. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 29040838157


int convert(int number, int system)
{
    int i=0;    

    while(number%system == 0)
    {
        i++;
        number/=system;
    }

    return i;
}

int main()
{   
    int i,max;
    int temp=0;

    for(i=2;i<=NUM;i++)
    {
        if(convert(NUM,i) >= temp)
        {
            max=i;
            temp = convert(NUM,max);
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n",max);
}
```

Solved.
It's wise to use `unsigned long long int` or represent number in an array.

Comment: Use a long? Or if the numbers will always be positive use an unsigned int or long.

Comment: _And I apologise for my english. It's not my main language_ - Understood. I think by "10 system" and "3 numeral system", you really mean "base 10" and "base 3".

Comment: Do you look for the highest base? Because if `10` is a solution, `2` and `5` is also a solution. `100000` in base 10 is `11000011010100000` in base 2 and so it has also 5 zeros at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For larger number, you should use data type which can store higher integer values too. I recommend `unsigned long long`

```
#define NUM 29040838157ULL //note the ULL here    

unsigned long long convert(unsigned long long number, unsigned long long system)
{
    int i=0;    

    while(number%system == 0)
    {
        i++;
        number/=system;
    }

    return i;
}

int main()
{   
    unsigned long long i,max;
    unsigned long long temp=0;

    for(i=2;i<=NUM;i++)
    {
        if(convert(NUM,i) >= temp)
        {
            max=i;
            temp = convert(NUM,max);
        }
    }

    printf("%llu\n",max);
}
```

And so on

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is merely prime factorisation. Find any program that does the prime factorisation of an integer. The prime factor with the highest count is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Potentially an interesting observation - but OP's example answer for `100 000`, `10`, is not a prime. Can you expand a bit?

Comment: @Jongware `100 000` has 5 zeros in base 2, 5 and 10. The smallest solution is always a prime. If there are 2 prime solutions you can multiply them for another solution. For example: the number `30` has 1 zero in the base 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15 and 30.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own long.
Create an array of variables, meaning the thousands of your original number.
INIT:
    Split your number
    Number = Number[0]+1000*Number[1]+1000000*Number[2]+...
    (For you to find out how to do that, it's not so difficult + you'll meet a new boundary, the size of your array.
INNER LOOP:
    Divide the highest array member by your i. Take the remainder (modulus).     Multiply by 1000 and add it to the next array member.
    b = Number[3]
    a = b - i*(b%i)
    b = 1000*a + Number[2]
    etc...
If the last a is zero, that's a hit.
You'll have to work on something to be able to divide another time. Feed a back into Number[3] or something.

It's an idea, you'll have to work out the details. I guess it's a programming excercise.

And if you're a real IT guy, you'll use 1024 in stead of 1000 :-).

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Long type (is greater than int) or add a control that say at you if the number is greater than the max int(that is 32767 or 65535 if it's unsigned)